# Optimize/ Vectorize Mahalanobis distance calculations in MATLAB

Tags: performance, matlab, optimization, matrix, vectorization

I have the following piece of Matlab code, which calculates [Mahalanobis distances](http://mathworks.com/help/stats/mahal.html) between a vector and a matrix with several iterations. I am trying to find a faster method to do this by vectorization but without success.

```
S.data=0+(20-0).*rand(15000,3);
S.a=0+(20-0).*rand(2500,3);

S.resultat=ones(length(S.data),length(S.a))*nan;
S.b=ones(length(S.a),3,length(S.a))*nan;

for i=1:length(S.data)
    for j=1:length(S.a)
         S.a2=S.a;
         S.a2(j,:)=S.data(i,:);
         S.b(:,:,j)=S.a2;
           if j==length(S.a)
              for k=1:length(S.a);
                   S.resultat(i,k)=mahal(S.a(k,:),S.b(:,:,k));
              end
           end    
    end   
end
```

I have now modified the code and avoid one of the loop. But it is still very long. If someone have an idea, I will be very greatful!

```
S.data=0+(20-0).*rand(15000,3);
S.a=0+(20-0).*rand(2500,3);

S.resultat=ones(length(S.data),length(S.a))*nan;
   for i=1:length(S.data)
       for j=1:length(S.a)
       S.a2=S.a;
       S.a2(j,:)=S.data(i,:);
       S.resultat(i,j)=mahal(S.a(j,:),S.a2);    
       end   
   end
```

Comment: What is that function `mahal`?

Comment: without knowing what the `mahal` function do it will be difficult to give any help. Can `mahal` operate on arrays ? Also, what are the size of `S.b` and `S.a` ?

Comment: Are you computing the Mahalanobis distance a'*inv(B)*a for a series of different vectors a and matrices B?

Comment: Also, your results don't appear to depend on loop variable i

Comment: Sorry for my incomplete post. mahal computes the Mahalnobis distance of each observation in S.a from the reference sample in matrix S.b. S.a and S.b must have the same number of columns but can have different numbers of rows. Here, S.a [2500x3] and S.b [2500x3x2500].

Comment: Yes Clark. And yes, my results depend on loop variable i because S.b is dependent of this loop variable i

Comment: How is `S.b` dependent on `i`? What's the role of `data`?

Comment: @Divakar, the matrice `data` is a general matrice used to calculated each new condition giving `S.b`

Comment: Stéphane - To make @Divakar 's assertion more clearer, your loop index `i` is **not** being used in your code when indexing `S.a` and `S.b`.  In fact, you are saying that **every** row will contain the same result.  Is this intentional?

Comment: @rayryeng - Sorry, it is my fault I am not clear. As I said, it is just a piece of code. I edited my first post to clarify the code

Comment: @Stéphane - That's fine, but even with your example, if you read it and take it at face value, then there is no need for the first `for` loop.  You could simply store the results in a single vector.  But if not, did you mean this instead? `S.resultat(i,j)=mahal(S.a(i,:),S.b(:,:,j));`.  Look at where the `i` is placed.

Comment: @rayryeng - With the complete code, I think it is better to understand why `i` can not be here.

McMa - Thanks, I did in this way because I am sure `data` will always have more rows than columns.

Comment: @Stéphane - Now the code makes more sense.  Without that complete code, we would have been unsure on how to optimize it.

Comment: @Stéphane - This code is going to be difficult to optimize because you have conditional branching inside your loops.  If each iteration was independent of the other iterations, then surely some `bsxfun` approach would be appropriate, but because of that `if` statement there, it's going to be more difficult.

Comment: @rayryeng - It was my fear! I understand why I am sticked since a long time now. I modified the code but It is still very long...

Comment: @Stéphane - OK, you made one change that I was going to suggest.  You actually didn't need the `if` statement there.  Let me see if I can do something with that code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Introduction and solution code

You can replace the innermost loop that uses **[`mahal`](http://in.mathworks.com/help/stats/mahal.html)** with something that is a *bit* vectorized, as it uses some pre-calculated values (with the help of `bsxfun`) inside a loop-shortened and hacked version of `mahal`.

Basically you have a `2D` array, let's call it `A` for easy reference and a `3D` array, let's call it `B`. Let the output be stored be into a variable `out`. So, the innermost code snippet could be extracted and based on the assumed variable names.

**Original loopy code**

```
for k=1:size(A,1)
    out(k)=mahal(A(k,:),B(:,:,k));
end
```

So, what I did was to hack into `mahal.m` and look for portions that could be vectorized when the inputs are `2D` and `3D`. Now, `mahal` uses `qr` inside it, which could not be vectorized. Thus, we end up with a *hacked* code.

**Hacked code**

```
%// Pre-calculate certain values that could be avoided than using into loop
meanB = mean(B,1); %// mean of B along dim-1
B_meanB = bsxfun(@minus,B,meanB); %// B minus mean values of B
A_B_meanB = A' - reshape(meanB,size(B,2),[]); %//'# A minus B_meanB 

%// QR calculations in a for-loop starts until the output is obtained
for k = 1:size(A,1)
    [~,R] = qr(B_meanB(:,:,k),0);
    out2(k) = sum((R'\A_B_meanB(:,k)).^2)*(size(A,1)-1);
end
```

Now, to extend this hack solution to the problem code, one can introduce few more tweaks to pre-calculate more values being used those nested loops.

**Final solution code**

```
A = S.a; %// Get data from S
[rx,cx] = size(A); %// Get size parameters
Atr = A'; %//'# Pre-calculate transpose of A

%// Pre-calculate replicated B and the indices to be modified at each iteration
B_rep = repmat(S.a,1,1,rx);
B_idx = bsxfun(@plus,[(0:cx-1)*rx + 1]',[0:rx-1]*(rx*cx+1)); %//'

out = zeros(size(S.data,1),rx); %// initialize output array
for i=1:length(S.data)

    B = B_rep;
    B(B_idx) = repmat(S.data(i,:)',1,rx); %//'
    meanB = mean(B,1); %// mean of B along dim-1

    B_meanB = bsxfun(@minus,B,meanB); %// B minus mean values of B
    A_B_meanB = Atr - reshape(meanB,3,[]); %// A minus B_meanB
    for jj = 1:rx
        [~,R] = qr(B_meanB(:,:,jj),0);
        out(i,jj) = sum((R'\A_B_meanB(:,jj)).^2)*(rx-1); %//'
    end

end
S.resultat = out;
```

---

### Benchmarking

Here's the benchmarking code to compare the proposed solution against the code listed in the problem -

```
%// Random inputs
S.data=0+(20-0).*rand(1500,3); %(size 10x reduced for a quicker runtime test)
S.a=0+(20-0).*rand(250,3);

S.resultat=ones(length(S.data),length(S.a))*nan;
disp('----------------------------- With original code')
tic

S.b=ones(length(S.a),3,length(S.a))*nan;
for i=1:length(S.data)
    for j=1:length(S.a)
        S.a2=S.a;
        S.a2(j,:)=S.data(i,:);
        S.b(:,:,j)=S.a2;
        if j==length(S.a)
            for k=1:length(S.a);
                S.resultat(i,k)=mahal(S.a(k,:),S.b(:,:,k));
            end
        end
    end
end

toc, clear i j S.a2 k S.resultat

S.resultat=ones(length(S.data),length(S.a))*nan;
disp('----------------------------- With proposed solution code')
tic

[ ... Proposed solution code ...]

toc
```

Runtimes -

```
----------------------------- With original code
Elapsed time is 17.734394 seconds.
----------------------------- With proposed solution code
Elapsed time is 6.602860 seconds.
```

Thus, we might get around **`2.7x`** speedup with the proposed approach and some tweaks!

Comment: @Divakar - Thanks for this suggestion. I try it now to have an idea!

Comment: @Divakar - Yes! I have the same runtime results as you, even if I used my modified code. Your solution run really faster! A longer code, more loops, but faster...sometimes Matlab is strange... The vectorization is a great idea!

Comment: @Stéphane Sweetest thing I heard today! Well function-inlining is one of the tools to speedup things in MATLAB, as done here. If you start playing with it, it doesn't look strange anymore :)

Comment: @Stéphane Did few more tweaks! Check it out.

Comment: @Divakar - Sorry for my late reply, I was without connection until now.Many thanks for your help, I runned your previous modification and it works great (the speedup is really impressive). I just tried your new approach, but I have some difficulties to perform it (definitively because I am a newbie in function-inlining). When I apply your code, Matlab warns me of an issue with repmat (too many input arguments) to create the variable 'B_rep' .... Sorry, I feel idiot...

Comment: @Stéphane See  if you do this instead, works or not - `B_rep = repmat(S.a,[1 1 rx]);`? By the way what version of MATLAB are you using? `S.a`is still `2500x 3`, right?

Comment: @Divakar - Your reply is so fast!! That works now. I am using MATLAB R2011b on my personal computer, so they may have changed the repmat function in latest versions. I used R2014b at work so I will see the difference tomorrow. Your hacked version is so clever! I am very grateful to you for your help.

Comment: @Stéphane Yeah that comes with working with it for sometime :) So, I would be really interested in seeing what kind of speedups you would be getting with the new approach against your original approach, if you don't mind getting some of those speedup numbers. Also, you can look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matlab+vectorization) for MATLAB related vectorization techniques.

Comment: @Divakar Many thanks for the link you send. I applied both approaches on my (not really fast) personal computer and I find an equivalent speedup: '----------------------------- With original code
Elapsed time is 46.771637 seconds.
----------------------------- With proposed solution code
Elapsed time is 16.291109 seconds.'

Comment: @Stéphane Very kool!! Thank you for getting those numbers for me!

Comment: @Divakar I will apply now both codes on 'real dataset', but I am sure the gain will be to the same extent. I let you now after the first test. I really need to learn vectorization techniques ;-)

Comment: Hi, Could you comment here: http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/232943-computing-mahalanobis-distance-between-set-of-points-and-set-of-reference-points. Thank You.