# How to change Euclidean distance to Mahalanobis distance in my MATLAB code?

Tags: matlab, euclidean-distance

I am trying to segment an image for a given k value using k-means clustering algorithm.

I want to change the distance calculation from Euclidean to Mahalanobis distance But I cannot implement the formula to my existing code because it has three dimensional array.

First I convert RGB image into HSL space. Then I label the pixels after distance calculation. In the last step I convert HSL image back into RGB space.

```
nC = uint8(input('Enter cluster number: '));

iRGB = double(imread('Bird.png'));

tic

iHSL = rgb2hsl(iRGB/255);

[ro co bd ] = size(iHSL);

% Randomly assign cluster positions
Cs = [randi(ro, nC,1) randi(co, nC,1)];

%create array for labels
Ls = zeros(ro, co);
%create another array for comparison of labels 
prev_Ls = ones(ro, co);

distances = zeros( 1, nC );

kcenter = zeros(nC, 3);

for k=1:nC
    kcenter(k,:) = iHSL(kcenter(k),kcenter(k,2),:);
end

while (true)

    prev_Ls = Ls;
    for r = 1:ro
        for c = 1:co 
            for k = 1:nC
                distances(k) = sqrt(((iHSL(r,c,1) - kcenter(k,1))^2 +...
                                     (iHSL(r,c,2) - kcenter(k,2))^2 +...
                                     (iHSL(r,c,3) - kcenter(k,3))^2));

            end

            d = find(distances(:) == min(distances));
            Ls(r,c) = d(1);
        end
    end

    H = zeros(1,nC);
    S = zeros(1,nC);
    L = zeros(1,nC);
    cnt = zeros(1,nC);

    for r = 1:ro
        for c = 1:co
            H( Ls(r,c) ) = H( Ls(r,c) ) + iHSL(r,c,1);
            S( Ls(r,c) ) = S( Ls(r,c) ) + iHSL(r,c,2);
            L( Ls(r,c) ) = L( Ls(r,c) ) + iHSL(r,c,3);
            cnt( Ls(r,c) ) = cnt( Ls(r,c) ) + 1;
        end
    end

    for k = 1:nC 
        kcenter(k,1) = H(k) / cnt(k);
        kcenter(k,2) = S(k) / cnt(k);
        kcenter(k,3) = L(k) / cnt(k);
    end

    %if prev_labels are equal to current labels break while loop.
    if isequal(prev_Ls, Ls)
        break;
    end    
end

for r = 1:ro
    for c = 1:co    
        iHSL(r,c,1) = kcenter(Ls(r,c), 1);
        iHSL(r,c,2) = kcenter(Ls(r,c), 2);
        iHSL(r,c,3) = kcenter(Ls(r,c), 3);
    end
end

result_img = hsl2rgb(iHSL)*255;

toc
figure(1);

subplot(1,2,1);
imshow(uint8(iRGB));
subplot(1,2,2);
imshow(uint8(result_img));
```

I want to change this formula with mahalanobis distance calculation formula. I have tried `mahal(iHSL(r,c,1),kcenter(k,1))` I got `Nan` result. 
All the examples on the Internet are for two dimensional arrays. But I have 3 dimensional.

I have tried to change this line;

```
distances(k) = sqrt((iHSL(r,c,1) - kcenter(k,1))^2 +...
                    (iHSL(r,c,2) - kcenter(k,2))^2 +...
                    (iHSL(r,c,3) - kcenter(k,3))^2);
```

to;

```
distances(k) =   mahal(kcenter(k,:), iHSL(:,:,1)) + ...
                 mahal(kcenter(k,:), iHSL(:,:,2)) + ...
                 mahal(kcenter(k,:), iHSL(:,:,3));
```

But it gives me an error saying:

> Error using mahal (line 34) Requires the inputs to have the same number of columns.

I do not know how to formulate Mahalanobis distance calculation for my 3d array.

Comment: I think `mahalanobis` internally performs left division, see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28114259/3293881). That `NaN` might be because of it.