# MATLAB: avoid loop when using a function within a matrix

Tags: algorithm, matlab, loops

I have a matrix A: "M x N". I want to run a function within a matrix,

e.g.,regression: let each column be a Y, rest column be Xs

```
    for i=1:N
        Y = A(:,i);   % let Y be the "i"th columns
        X = A; X(:,i)=[];     % let X be other columns
        coef(:,i)=regress(Y,X);
    end
```

i wonder if there is any matlab function is able to handle a function in a loop

Comment: Looked into `regress` and seems like it's complicated enough for a vectorization, so if you ask me, might not be worth it. But on optimzation at the listed code level, you can precompute `X` before going into loop and use it iteratively.

Comment: If you don't have many/any `NaN`'s in your data, you can do `coeff(:,i)=X\Y`. Might be faster than `regress`. Using the `qr` to solve the system might even be faster than backslash. @Divakar what do you think? Would that enable any more vectorisation magic?

Comment: @David Well looking into `regress`, it seems it has few norm calculations, where vectorization could be applied, but the performance bottleneck there seems to be `tinv`, which I am guessing is the backslash thing you are talking about. Not sure if `qr` could be used there, as I don't know much about it or the performance numbers associated with them.

Comment: If `qr` could be used, [`this solution`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28114259/3293881) might be worth a look.

Comment: I want some ideas that can get me two matrices ("one column" and "other columns") out in each loop. i feel like there could be a better solution than a for loop. Do you have any idea, e.g., to transfer them into X and Y cells array? where each X cell is a X matrix (Matrix A less one column), each Y cell is a Y vector

Comment: @FF0605 I have a hunch that a single for loop will outperform any cell-based solution.

Answer (score 1):

This should be MUCH faster!

```
[n_rows, n_cols] = size(A);
ind = true(1,n_cols);
coef2 = zeros(n_cols - 1, n_cols);

for i=1:n_cols
    y = A(:,i);   % let Y be the "i"th columns
    ind(i) = false;
    X = A(:,ind);     % let X be other columns
    coef2(:,i)= X\y;
    ind(i) = true;
end
```

Differences between my code and yours:

1. X \ y gives you regression coefficients of y on X. (Most important)
2. I don't resize matrices.